# Check for duplicate value

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Suppose I have the following table:

```
PERSON :
ID INT
NAME STRING
LASTNAME STRING
```

In my CRUD application I cannot allow the user to insert an existing `NAME-LASTNAME` combination. What is the best way to do this? The user can either be inserting a new person, or editing one that already exists.

Comment: Do you have access to the DB? Can you put a UNIQUE constraint on those 2 columns?

Comment: yes i have access.but i can't use unique because my table has a property (bool isActive), and the validation has to be done only if the person is active.

Comment: You mean if the person is not flagged active it is ok to have duplicates ? This does not sound very coherent you better stick to a single behaviour in all cases to avoid a mess in your db. 
Anyways, you could simply perform the check via an NHibernate  request before inserting, what about that ?

Comment: There are two possiblities that I can see: 1) Use an insert trigger and do the validation there. 2) Do the validation in the code.

Comment: @AlexMendez I'm sadly not sure Oracle supports any isolation mode that would let you manually do a safe unique check/insert without a full table lock. Happy to be proven wrong though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not specifying the database, but if you're using SQL Server 2008 or newer, you should create a composite UNIQUE index on the columns, in your case since only active users should be unique, a filtered one;

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uix ON PERSON(NAME, LASTNAME) WHERE ACTIVE=1;
```

This index will only index active users and disallow duplicates on them only.

Comment: I'm using nhibernate with ORACLE

Comment: With filtered indexes missing in Oracle, the only database-enforceable option I can see is mapping isActive into a NULLabe DATE (call it deactivatedAt maybe), null means an active user, a time is a timestamp when it was deactivated. You should be able to make that mapping in NHibernate to an isActive bool and it will let you have a UNIQUE index on name/lastname/deactivatedAt.

Comment: This does not fix the OP's problem, but that's good to know. I was not aware of such a possibility. Nice